# Right Click Context menu - Menu Item name is location of right click target

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, context-menu, context

Is it possible to add an option to the right click context menu that has a dynamic name?  Meaning the name could change?  I'd like to (for fun) have a menu option added with a name that would be the location of where the right click took place.

For example if I right clicked the background of the desktop the menu item that I added would have the name `C:\Users\me\Desktop`

**Or** if I right click the background of documents the name of the menu item that I added would have the name `C:\Users\me\Documents`

Comment: Oh yes, absolutely. You’ll have to write a shell extension. But I’m not sure whether this question is on-topic.

Comment: @DanielB Question on topic?  Meaning there may be a better place for this question?  Like stack overflow?

Comment: In my opinion this is on topic, as it asks how rather than focusing on the code part. This question does not explicitly reference shell extension, so this post should stay on SuperUser. But you should inquiry Stack Overflow, if you accept shell extension as an answer or code as an answer

Comment: @El8tedN8te I feel the same.  Thanks.

Comment: @DanielB I have very little experience writing a shell etension.  The only time I did I was blindly following a tutorial on pluralsight.  But from that experience you make .rgs files that when the dll is registered with the windows os it makes entries into the registry to implement the context menu.  So I should be able to do that manually yes?

Comment: No. A shell extension’s context menu entries are generated on-the-fly by executing code. I can’t find any example code right now though, because it’s arcane technology.